# Is it an anti pattern if state A depends on state B and state B updates depend on A?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose you have an app where a user can select items from a menu. When a user selects an item we detach the container, create a new container and attach the selected item to the latest container.

Right now whenever user selects an item I update the state `selectedInfo`. Once this happens I use a useEffect to detach the container state and update it.

```
useEffect(detachContainer, [selectedInfo]);
```

Once the container gets updated to latest value I want it to attach to the new `selectedInfo`. I do this as follows:

```
useEffect(() => attachToLatestInfo(selectedInfo), [container]);
```

This second `useEffect` gives a missing dependency warning. I know this can be suppressed easily but I'm wondering whether doing so can hurt me later on.
Overall I'm wondering if state dependency like this is an anti pattern or not

Comment: It's hard to know for sure with a simple hypothetical like this. If you're updating `A` based on `B`, then maybe `A` could just be derived from `B` instead of stored in state at all? But like I said, hard to say with such a simple hypothetical.

Comment: Okay I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Updated the question @BrianThompson please let me know what you think.